# Size for HSQL Timestamp and Boolean data type?

Tags: java, database, hsqldb

I am trying to assess how much memory a specific `HSQL in-memory` table is taking

I followed http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/guide.html#sgc_types_ops to find out
how much respective Data type (in byte) takes

```
INTEGER
4 

VARCHAR
1

INTEGER
4

TIMESTAMP
?

BOOLEAN
?
```

I could not find for `Timestamp` and `Boolean`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In-memory databases store data as Java objects in arrays. Therefore the reference to each object takes 8 bytes in a 64 bit memory space to store.

The size of each object varies and could be 16 bytes for Java Integer. VARACHAR is stored as Java String.

BOOLEAN is stored as Java Boolean. As there are only two Boolean objects, there is no extra overhead for a BOOLEAN column

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/deployment-chapt.html#dec_mem_disk_use